# Get the id of the selected value in a dropdown validation list on Excel in VBA

Tags: vba, validation, excel

Using Excel, lets say I have a validation list made of 5 values like this one :

```
Patate
Tomate
Courgette
Concombre
Patate
```

In a cell containing a drop down list made of these 5 value, I select the fifth value : "Patate". 
I want to get in VBA that this cell contains the 5th value of my validation list. Something like :

> x = Cell.Validation.GetIDValueSelected
>
> x = 5

I can't use Vertical search because I might have 2 or even more time the same value in my list (too long to explain why). 
This list is also dynamics (depending of another sheets) so it doesn't always contains 5 values.

I hope I made it clear for everyone to understand my needs but I will be glad to add more information if needed. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of having duplicate values in the drop down list. You can delete duplicates. Problem is there is no direct way to get what you are trying to do. That property does not exist

Comment: Ok that was I though...
I find a very benefit way of having duplicate values but it is not the main purpose of validation list so I understand why this property doesn't exist. Thank you Jeanno !

Comment: I was just going to say that Excel has  a built-in capability to delete duplicates from very long lists

Comment: Actually, i might have the same value in a list because I build one list from multiple collumns (forming a tree of value). And deepness of tree is made with spaces.

Comment: So the duplicates are children of different parents in the tree? If so, then Gary's Student's answer is right, you won't be able to tell. You would have to find a way to make the item unique. (i.e. include the parent in the child name - parent1:child, parent2:child)

Comment: Yep that what I though... Sadly my list would look terrible but it migh be the only solution. Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, once you have used *DV* to fill a cell with **junk,** there is no way to tell which piece of **junk** you picked:

[image]

You would have to pad each piece of **junk** with a different number of blanks.